# Авторизация на .dat файлах

Tags: php

**Форма:**

```html
<form action='login.php' method='post'>
  <input type='email' name='email'><br>
  <input type='password' name='pass'><br>
  <input type='submit'><br>
</form>
```

Папка с данными от акаунтов: ../../acc/$id/info/
**Главный код:**
http://pastebin.com/3pQ1tKAg
**Примечание:**

Всегда выводит "ok".

**Суть авторизации:**

Циклом открывает файлы с паролями и логинами и проверяет совпадают ли  они с вводимыми

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42792/discussion-on-question-by-bedomar---dat-).

Answer (score 3):

**Никогда не делайте так в реальных проектах**

Ваш код можно переделать примерно так. Изначально юзер не авторизован, `$success = FALSE;`. Если есть куки, и куки не фальшивый – предоставлен также хэш, который невозможно вычислить, не зная секретную «соль», известную только серверу – юзер автризован.

Далее, если кук нет, но есть POST-запрос с email и pass, ищем в туче файлов совпадение email'а, и совпадение хэша от переданного пароля с хранимым в dat-файлах хэшем. Храним не сам пароль, а `md5( $pass . $salt)`. Это в простейшем варианте.

Если нашлось, ставим `$success = TRUE`.   После всех этих плясок смотрим, что в `$success`, и показываем то, либо сё.

```
<?php

$success = FALSE;
$salt = '7v#eLVVBjiT8Ma7rA'; // здесь ваша сверхсекретная строка
// на её неизвестности другим держится вся «безопасность»

if( isset($_COOKIE['id'], $_COOKIE['hash'])) {

    if( md5( $_COOKIE['id'] . $salt) === $_COOKIE['hash']) {
        $success = TRUE;
    } else {
        // тревога! Волк унёс зайчат!
        die('Вы, наверное, кул хакер?');
    }

} else if( isset( $_POST['email'], $_POST['pass'])) {

    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $pass = $_POST['pass'];

    $count_id = file_get_contents('../register/count_id.dat');
    for($i=1; $i<$count_id; $i++) {
        $id = "id".$i;
        $email_acc      = file_get_contents("../../acc/$id/info/email.dat");
        $pass_acc       = file_get_contents("../../acc/$id/info/pass.dat");
        $nickname_acc   = file_get_contents("../../acc/$id/info/nickname.dat");

        if( $email === $email_acc  &&  md5($pass . $salt) === $pass_acc) {

            setcookie("id", $id, time() + 99999999, "/");
            setcookie("hash", md5($id . $salt), time() + 99999999, "/");
            setcookie("nickname", $nickname_acc, time() + 99999999, "/");
            $success = TRUE;
            break; // дальше крутить цикл не нужно
        }
    }
}


if( $success) {
    echo "ok";
    //echo "Ви вже авторизовані";
} else {
    echo <<<EOFHTML
        <script type="text/javascript">
            setTimeout(function(){$(".nopass").fadeOut("fast")},10000);
        </script>
        <div class="nopass">
            <h4>Неправильний логін або пароль!</h4>
        </div>
EOFHTML;
}
```

---

Что-то готовое для авторизации – возьмите какой-то нетяжёлый фреймворк, или готовый компонент, [например](https://github.com/PHPAuth/PHPAuth), на [github'е](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=php+authentication).

Comment: плюс, хотя бы потому, что подумать и погуглить заставит слегка

Comment: Ошыбок не выводит но при вводе правильных данных всё равно пишет неправильный пароль

Comment: Вы пересоздали файлы с паролями, чтобы там был не сам пароль, а его хэш?